# My prolog program doesn't stop when my list is empty

Tags: list, prolog

I don't get why my program doesn't stop when my input list is empty eventhough there's a fact which can handle that case. Here's my code:

```
    build_vps([], []).
    build_vps([X | Ys], Zs):-
             atom_number(X, C),
             number(C),
             build_vps(Ys, Zs).
    build_vps([X, Y, Z | Ys], Zs):-
             Y = '^',
             atom_number(Z, C),
             number(C),
             build_vps(Ys, [v(C,  X) | Zs]).
    build_vps([X, Y, Z | Ys], [v(1, X)| Zs]):-
             Y \= '^',
             build_vps([Y, Z | Ys], Zs).
```

I have a list of character like this [x, ^, '3] and I should put those characters into a structure like this v(3, x). Im calling it like this build_vps([x, y, ^, '3'], R). What im trying to achieve is R = [v(1, x), v(3, y)].

Comment: Can you show how you call this from the top level? And maybe some explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: When you write a recursive predicate with a list in the first argument, try as hard as you can to have exactly two clauses: `foo([]...).` and `foo([H|T], ...) :- ..., foo(T, ...).`.

Comment: You should edit your answer and show **exactly** how you load the file, how you do the query, and what happens. Right now, for me, running `?- build_vps([x, y, ^, 3], R).` (I had to add a comma after `^`) gives me `ERROR: atom_number/2: Type error: 'atom' expected, found '3' (an integer)`. So I cannot reproduce your error with what you've given me.

Comment: you're typing it wrong. 3 has to be a character, so it should be ' 3 '.

Comment: When I type it just like you suggest, I get just a `false`.

Comment: Ye I know that but I don't get why. If u trace it, you'll see it keeps going when it reaches 0 elements in the first list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does stop. it simply says `False` because it could not match any of your rules.

> Yes, I know that but I don't get why. If u trace it, you'll see it keeps going when it reaches 0 elements in the first list.

It does not, what you are seeing is the call to

```
build_vps(Ys, [v(C,  X) | Zs]).
```

Now, you did not provide enough information for what you want this program to do, but I am guessing that once you have `[y, ^, '3']` you want it to match with the third rule.

If this is the case, the reason the program fails is that it cannot match this: `build_vps(Ys, [v(C,  X) | Zs]).`

You can confirm this by trying: `build_vps([], [v(3,  y) | Zs]).`

This can be easily solved by rewriting the third rule to this:

```
build_vps([], []).

build_vps([X | Ys], Zs):-
         atom_number(X, C),
         number(C),
         build_vps(Ys, Zs).

/* 
 * This rule has been modified 
 */
build_vps([X, Y, Z | Ys], [v(C, X) | Zs]):-
         Y = '^',
         atom_number(Z, C),
         number(C),
         build_vps(Ys, Zs).

build_vps([X, Y, Z | Ys], [v(1, X)| Zs]):-
         Y \= '^',
         build_vps([Y, Z | Ys], Zs).
```

Comment: Ye thanks, it was pretty stupid of me. It works now, Had to add a new rule too because the program didn't work when I had only 2 elements in the list. Thanks!!